# 画像判別AIモデルのloss率とacc率を良くしたい

Tags: python, docker, 機械学習, 深層学習

うさぎとカメの判別AIの開発をしています。
しかし、なぜか学習がうまくいかず、lossやacc（判別成功率）の値が良くなりません。
通常、lossとaccは反比例で片方の数値が増加すればもう片方が減少するはずなのに、lossが膨大に増加してaccは0.5あたりで変化しません。
これはニューラルネットワークの設計がいけないのでしょうか？？
以下に、スペックとソースコードと結果画面を載せます。

仕様スペック
・windows10
・Docker
・Python3.7.3

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gc
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils

class TrainModel : 
  def __init__(self):
    input_dir = './Gazo'
    self.nb_classes = len([name for name in os.listdir(input_dir) if name != ".DS_Store"])
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = np.load("./Gakushu.npy")
    # データを正規化する
    self.x_train = x_train.astype("float") / 256
    self.x_test = x_test.astype("float") / 256
    self.y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, self.nb_classes)
    self.y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, self.nb_classes)
  def train(self, input=None) :
    model = Sequential()
    # K=32, M=3, H=3
    if input == None :
      model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=self.x_train.shape[1:]))
    else :
      model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=input))
    # K=64, M=3, H=3（調整）
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    # K=64, M=3, H=3（調整）
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten()) 
    model.add(Dense(512))
    # biases  nb_classes
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(self.nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    if input == None :
      # 学習してモデルを保存
      model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=int(kaisu), validation_data=(self.x_test,self.y_test))
      hdf5_file = "./AImodel.hdf5"
      model.save_weights(hdf5_file)
      score = model.evaluate(self.x_test, self.y_test, verbose = 0)
      print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
      print("")
      print("トレーニング終了！")
      print("")
      print('loss=', score[0])
      print('判別成功率=', score[1])
      print("")
    return model
if __name__ == "__main__":
  args = sys.argv
  train = TrainModel()
  train.train()
  gc.collect()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考ページ：https://qiita.com/tsunaki/items/608ff3cd941d82cd656b

Answer (score 0):

Epochの2以降は学習できていない状態ですね。
168枚というデータ枚数に対して、モデル構造が複雑すぎるためだと推察します。
data augmentationによって訓練データの枚数を増やすか、もしくは畳み込み層やプーリング層におけるフィルタの大きさや枚数を減らすのが良いと思います。
また、乱数値の設定状態によって訓練する度に結果が変わってしまうので、予め設定しておくと良いと思います。